# How to test Rasa Chatbot in Bot Emulator

Tags: rasa, rasa-core

I want to know if we can test the rasa chatbot in bot emulator. If yes, what are the steps, since bot emulator accepts only end point which ends with “/api/messages”. What are the commands that should be executed in the command prompt. and what is the port number that should be given in bot emulator.

Thanks:)

Comment: Do you want to use the Microsoft Bot Emulator with Rasa?

Comment: yes @BeppeC. I want to use rasa with bot emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a little test I ran, you can use Bot Emulator with Rasa. What you have to configure is a custom webhook which can be done by creating a custom connector and defining a webhook (it can end with "/api/messages" but it works without it as well). If you do that, then the bot url you would provide would look something like the following "http://localhost:5005/webhooks/custom_connector_module/webhook/api/messages".

Overall, using Rasa X Community Edition would probably be the best option to test your bot with a simple UI. Have you looked into it?